# Why can't I map over a response object from an API as it is in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

I have got what I need working but I do not fully understand why it is working.

I am using ReactJS and I have some code that requests an API from a server and displays it on my screen. I have this code:

```
let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState([])

   const response = async (e) => {
       e.preventDefault()
       await axios.get('https://newsdata.io/api/1/news?apikey=<api_key>&q=tennis ')
       .then(response => {
           console.log((response.data.results))
           setResponseData((response.data.results))
       }).catch(function (error) {
           if (error.response) {
             console.log(error.response.data);
             console.log(error.response.status);
             console.log(error.response.headers);
} 
       })
   }
   return (
       <div>
         
           <button onClick={(e) => response(e)} type='button'>Click Me For Data</button>
           {
               responseData.map(( data, i ) => (
                   <div key={i}>
                       <h2>{data.title}</h2> 
                       <h3>{data.link}</h3>
                       </div>
               ))
           }
```

This works as I want it to, however, previously I had my useState set to this:

```
let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState('')
```

I had seen that in my console that the response data that it was returning was already an array of objects. So I figured all I would have to do was to map over it since it's already an array. But I was getting an error that "responseData.map is not a function". After some thinking I thought it was because the useState was not starting off as an array to store each new responseData entry.

I changed it to React.useState([]) and it started working.

But now I'm confused because when I was console logging my response data, it was already appearing as "(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]" and when I used the "typeOf" operator it was saying that this is an object. But isn't it showing an array of objects because of the square brackets? That's why I thought the map() function would work on it. But now it seems I'm storing these entries in an array from useState. So I thought I would be making an array of an array of objects. But this is obviously not the case as it is working normally.

Why is the above an object and not an array and why does my code work now?

Comment: Hi. You now need to get a new API key since you've shared it with everyone here.

Comment: In answer to your question: your initial state that the component tries to render was initialised as an empty string, and `map` won't work on an empty string since it's an array method. Initialising the state to an empty array will, therefore, eliminate the error. When your state is updated by your fetch request you're updating it with _another_ array which is when you see the component rendering that data.

Comment: Also note you should be setting your API key with an env variable in a template string.

Comment: In addition to what Andy and dropex7 said, arrays are objects. 
let myArr = [];
console.log(typeof myArr);
console.log(Array.isArray(myArr));
this will log: 
"object"
true

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of all non-primitive values in JavaScript is object-based.
Simply put, JavaScript has a single prototypical object from which all other objects get their initial properties.

Initially, when you did `useState('')` ​​the initial value was string, since string does not have a map method, you received an error, if you set the initial value to `useState([])`, then the map will work correctly